# How can I stop my html image from spinning after all spins are complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/hmN7a/) which attempts to spin an image whenever the user clicks on the image.  If the user clicks the image once and doesn't click it again it stops spinning after one attempt like I intended.  Then they can click the image again and it will spin again.

But if they click the image once and then click it again it speeds up, which is also the correct behavior.  But then it won't stop spinning ever.

```
    if(degree === 361){
        clearInterval($this.data('rotating'));
        $this.data('rotating', false);
        $this.data('degree', 0);
        return;
    }
```

This code should stop it spinning after the second rotate is over but it just continues to spin indefinitely.  How can I get it to speed up and then stop spinning after the last spin per click is done?

Comment: try this 

`if(degree === 359)`

Comment: Nope that still shows the same behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is your problem:

When you are clicking it, you are assigning the value returned by `setInterval` to the data attribute of your element. This clobbers out any previous `setInterval` value you had stored, so they are never cleared. Instead of clobbering out the last one whenever you start a new one, you need to store them all. You can accomplish this by pushing each new value onto an array, and then pop off the last value of the array and clear that one each time you need to clear.

(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmN7a/8/)

```
$(function() {

    var $rota = $('.spin')
    var rotating=[];
    $rota.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        //push the latest interval id onto the array
        rotating.push(setInterval(function(){
            var degree = $this.data('degree') || 0;
            if(degree === 361){
                clearInterval(rotating.pop()); //clear out the latest inerval in the array
                $this.data('rotating', false);
                $this.data('degree', 0);
                return;
            }
            $this.css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
            $this.data('degree', ++degree)
        }, 5));

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this code to stop the rotation:

```
    if($this.data('rotating')) {
        $this.css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
        $this.data('degree', ++degree)
    }
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmN7a/6/

Hope this helps.

Comment: that will prevent it from rotating indefinitely, but only rotates once per click.

Answer (score -1):

Use clearInterval function.

```
if(degree === 161){
    clearInterval($this.data('rotating'));
    $this.data('rotating', false);
    $this.data('degree', 0);
    return clearInterval(this);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SkUV9/

Comment: Huh? He is using it, and you can't clear it with 'this'.

Comment: Your fiddle is broken beyond imagination... The image stops halfway

Comment: See condition... "if(degree === 161){" Good morning, it's a good day.